Error while running the Django exe file created by PyInstaller
I am using Pyinstaller to convert my Django project to a standalone executable file. WHen i run the exe file, i get the following error in the window. Can you please tell me what the error means and where should i check to rectify the error. Is this because i am not giving any input in the command line like "python manage.py runserver" while running the exe file? or is it related to something else
`Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 28, in <module>
      File "manage.py", line 24, in main
      File "django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute
        sys.stdout.write(self.main_help_text() + '\n')
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
`

